# Connecting desktop application to a live database on my hosting

Tags: java, mysql, database, livedb

I built a desktop application with mysql database using workbench but now i want my application to be used on multiple pc's and for that i will have to connect the database to my hosting i have copied the tables to hosting and now i m unable to connect to it.[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUu5Y.png)
              Connection conn = null;

```
public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306/internship_data_base","username","pass");
return conn;
}catch(Exception e){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

This is how i connect with mysql workbench and if i change it to my hosting's url it say no driver found for this .

Comment: Can you elloborate, as what is the error when you use it the stack trace

Comment: stack trace is added!